# How to play FEAR 3 over a LAN?

Tags: fear-3

I would like to play FEAR 3 cooperative mode over a LAN with my brother. Unfortunately we have no internet connection at home, but it's only available to play it on the internet.

Is it possible somehow, to play it on LAN, or connect to the host by IP?

Comment: What system ? PC/XBOX 360/ PS3?

Comment: PC - Windows7 and WindowsXP

Comment: Seeing as @speakr is right, there is no LAN support.  You would have to mod the game to get this to work.  ( kind of off-topic/ gray area here)

Comment: @Foxtrot If there is no way to play it over LAN, then I bring it back to the shop. I just wanted to play coop with my bro

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, FEAR 3 has no LAN support. You have to be online to play multiplayer games.

Comment: I know it...  But I hope, it is possible somehow.

Comment: It probably needs to talk with FEAR servers, so it cant access them from your place.

Comment: I can't understand the FEAR developers. Why should I be online, to play over LAN?

Comment: You can ask the same question regarding Diablo III single player..